# How to align icon with title in SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, swiftui, title, navigationbar

Can someone explain me how to reproduce the title bar of the app store, with an icon on the right that will disappear when scrolling down. And the title will be changing to inline display mode. You can find in attachment two pictures.

Thanks

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8El2S.png)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwH4F.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Apple natively supports adding items to the navigation bar using `navigationBarItems(...)`. To add an icon item to the right side of the header, use `navigationBarItems(trailing:)`:

```swift
NavigationView {
  ScrollView {
    ...
  }
  .navigationTitle("Title")
  .navigationBarItems(trailing: MyIconView())
}
```

If you have trouble switching from the large header to inline header when scrolling, you may need to add `navigationBarTitle(_:displayMode")` instead:

```swift
// Replaces .navigationTitle(...)
.navigationBarTitle("Title", displayMode: .large)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want the icon aligned with the large title, and when i scroll down I want the title only in the navbar, without the icon. Just like in the App Store...